# Adding cifres from left excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I have a sheet with some datas in D column. I need to extract the values that have less then 11 characters and adding from left many `0` untill reach 11 characters.. I explain with an example:

```
12345678912 --> this is correct
123456789 --> this is incorrect and has 9 characters so i need adding from left 2 zeros

result:
00123456789 --> now is correct
```

Is there a macro or a formula that could be useful for my goal? Thanks

Comment: I have about 10000 rows to check.. is there an automathic function? Or something like that?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the data is stored as numbers, you can simply use `=TEXT(A1,"00000000000")`. If it's stored as text then use `=REPT("0",LEN(A1)-11))&A1`

Comment: i have an error typing =TEXT(A1,"00000000000")

Comment: depending on your local settings, you might need to replace the `,` with your local separator (e.g. `;`)... Else A1 is probably not a number, then try the other formula.

Comment: + 1 As simple as that :)